# Выбрасывает из Visual Studio при включенном интернете

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

ПО:

1. Visual Studio 2022
2. Windows 11

Открываю студию, какой-либо проект, выкидывает без сообщения об ошибках через минуту-две.
Если отключить интеренет, то работает стабильно.
Пробовал удалять студию, ставить заново. Не помогло.

Comment: Студия какая? ломанная Pro+ или Community&

Comment: Enterprise, ломаная. До этого стояла Communiaty, установленная через оф. сайт через инсталятор. То де самое было.

Comment: нет мыслей. Скорее всего - это косяки 11-й. На 10-ке все работает

Comment: у меня 11 и работает корректно // на трех разных постах

Comment: Смотрите в журналы Windows (Управление компьютером - Журналы), ищите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: На другом компе стоит 22 студия, windows 10. Тоже работает корректно. Наверное, надо в журнал ОС посмотреть таки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снёс 11, поставил 10-ку.
Проблема исчезла.